# Broadcom NetLink BCM5906M driver

Tags: device-driver

I have bought a laptop today, but I'm not able to find the ethernet controller driver.
The drivers from Broadcom and Google are not the same version and are not compatible.
Can someone tell me where can I download BCM5906M driver for Windows XP, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question for Superuser.com, not Stack Overflow.

Knowing the make and model of the laptop would be useful, since Broadcom products may be customized by the OEM that integrates them into their system. A Dell laptop with this chip in it may require different drivers than a ASUS laptop with the same chip due to implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Needed it also for Win 7 today and found it [here](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtreme_desktop.php)

Works fine.

For XP try a driver from [Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-68016)